# BACS Statistics

Tags: networking, broadcom

There are two statistics from the BACS I am wondering if I should be concerned about:
[image]

They are Out of Recv. Buffer and Rx. Packet Discarded. It looks like Out of Recv. Buffer is the cause of all the discard? In general will this just cause a TCP retransmit? They are pretty low counts, but are they a cause of concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this on a Windows box? If so, bring up perfmon and add the counters for Network Interface/Packets Receieved Errors for the interface(s) in question and see what it shows. I'm pretty sure MS considers anyhting above 0 a problem.

Comment: Monitoring this now with SNMP via IF-MIB ifInDiscards

Answer (score 2):

> Buffer is the cause of all the discard?

CPU does not have time to handle all interrupts and buffer overflows. Therefore, packets drop.

> In general will this just cause a TCP retransmit?

maybe, but you can see statistical TCP over netstat.

> They are pretty low counts, but are they a cause of concern?

You can not worry too much small percentage drop.